# Hardware/Software requirements to run 5 VMs concurrently?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need some quick preliminary information about VMs, such as the baseline hardware/software reqs for running 5 VMs on one machine with decent performance. Would I be able to use VirtualBox without any problems? Also, what kind of performance can I expect?

As I'm sure you can tell I'm fairly inexperienced and am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with these VM, as you know, you need to dedicate some memory and other resouces to them...

> In order to run VirtualBox on your machine, you need Reasonably
>   powerful x86 hardware. Any recent Intel or AMD processor should do. 
>   Memory. Depending on what guest operating systems you want to run, you
>   will need at least 512 MB of RAM (but probably more, and the more the
>   better). Basically, you will need whatever your host operating system
>   needs to run comfortably, plus the amount that the guest operating
>   system needs. So, if you want to run Windows 8.1 on Windows 7, you
>   probably won't enjoy the experience much with less than 2 GB of RAM.
>   Check the minimum RAM requirements of the guest operating system, they
>   often will refuse to install if it is given less. Sometimes it
>   malfunctions instead. So you'll need that for the guest alone, plus
>   the memory your operating system normally needs.
>
> Hard disk space. While VirtualBox itself is very lean (a typical
>   installation will only need about 30 MB of hard disk space), the
>   virtual machines will require fairly huge files on disk to represent
>   their own hard disk storage. So, to install Windows 8, for example,
>   you will need a file that will easily grow to several 10 GB in size.
>
> A supported host operating system. Presently, we support Windows, many
>   Linux distributions, Mac OS X, Solaris and OpenSolaris. Check the user
>   manual of the VirtualBox version you are using which versions are
>   supported. For the latest VirtualBox version, see manual.
>
> A supported guest operating system. Besides the user manual (see
>   below), up-to-date information is available at "Status: Guest OSes".

Source: [VirtualBox Official Doc](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/End-user_documentation)